# Custom powershell prompt is clearing $lastexitcode

Tags: command-line, powershell

My powershell profile has a custom powershell prompt that unfortunately causes $lastexitcode values to be lost.  For instance, given a powershell script "fail.ps1" with contents "exit 123", when I run the script, $? is $false while $lastexitcode is 0.  If I instead run powershell without loading my profile with the custom prompt, after running fail.ps1 then $lastexitcode is 123.

Has anyone seen this problem before?  Is there a way to preserve $lastexitcode as the prompt is generated?

I ran into this when using Posh-git, https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git, a nice powershell prompt for git.

Comment: What does your prompt look like?

Comment: If you suspect the problem is in the prompt definition make a comparison using `(get-item function:prmpt).definition` on both prompts.

Comment: Interesting, $LastExitCode should only be impacted by calls to native applications.  Are you calling an exe from your prompt?  If so, go with @dahlbyk's answer.

Comment: I tested in PowerShell 3 on Windows 8, and the exit code from native .EXEs is correctly preserved without needing dahlbyk's fix. Previous versions may differ.

Comment: Yes bart, the issue in posh-git was fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue can be resolved by capturing `$LASTEXITCODE` at the start of the prompt and restoring it at the end:

```
function prompt {
    $realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE

    # ...

    $LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
 }
```

Comment: I thought I tried that and it didn't work, I must have had a type or something.  thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this to make it work:

```
function prompt {
    $realLASTEXITCODE = $global:LASTEXITCODE

    # ...

    $global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
    # cleanup
    Remove-Variable realLASTEXITCODE
 }
```